# SilverStripe: apply GreaterThanFilter class on multiple fields joining with OR

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. In my project, I am customizing the search within CMS. I am using the GreaterThanFilter for a date field as follows.

```
$filters['DateFrom'] = GreaterThanFilter::create('CreatedAt');
```

But I want to apply that same instance for multiple columns joining with OR for the condition. I tried using the following code.

```
$filters['DateFrom'] = GreaterThanFilter::create('CreatedAt', 'UpdatedAt');
```

But it did not work. Is it possible to do what I want to do and how?

Comment: Do you have some more code or context to share? Where are you trying to filter the CMS? Which hook do you use?